# utterly confused regarding bash script command line arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hadoop, command-line-arguments

I have the following bash script file callee.sh  which is being called from another script file caller.sh.

The callee.sh is as follows:

```
if [ $1 -eq  1 ];
then    
    echo  inside $1
    source ~/MYPROGRAMSRC/standAloneWordCount.sh $2
    #echo "inside standalone branch"
    #echo $1

elif [  $1 -eq  2  ];
then
    #echo "inside distributed branch"
    #echo $1

else
    echo invalid option for first argument-\n Options:\n "distributed"\n or\n "standalone"\n 


fi
```

As most people might be able to tell, this is a script I use to decide whether to run hadoop in distributed or standAlone mode depending on the arguments.

This script is called from caller.sh as follows

```
source callee.sh $2 $counterGlobal
```

where $2 is a number either 1 or 2 and $counterGlobal is some integer.

My problem is that the if condition in callee.sh never evaluates to True and hence my script standAloneWordCount.sh which I call from within callee.sh is never called. I am running with bash shell and have tried many variants of the if statement like:

```
if [ $(($1 == 1 )) ]  -- (1)
```

In an echo statement just above the line -- (1) , the expression $(($1 == 1)) evaluates to 1 so I am baffled as to why I am unable to satisfy the if condition.

Also I keep getting the error where it says:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `else'
```

if anyone could help me out with these two errors, it would be much appreciated. As I've run out of ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have tried many variants of the if statement like:
>
> `if [ $(($1 == 1 )) ]`

You should instead be saying:

```
if (($1 == 1)); then
  ...
fi
```

---

Regarding the `Syntax error near unexpected token`else'`, it's not because of any code that you've shown above.  It seems to originate from some other portion of your script.

Comment: well actually turns out there was something else wrong as it keep saying everytime I closed and re-opened the file that something had gone wrong and that the .swp file was being used. So I deleted the .swp file and your solution worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash, try using double square brackets:

```
if [[ $1 -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "inside 1"
fi
```

As for the `syntax error`, you need quotes around your text (which also means escaping the existing quotes or use single quotes):

```
echo -e "invalid option for first argument-\n Options:\n \"distributed\"\n or\n \"standalone\"\n"
```

The `-e` flag is there to let bash know you want the `\n` to evaluate to a newline.